# rmi java program not expected output

Tags: java

The rmi program when run asks a command.

If I gave ipconfig it works,but does not works for ping www.google.com and powercfg/batteryreport etc. I think it does not works if their is a space or slash between the input command.

Any help would be appreciated

si.java

```
 import java.rmi.*;
 import java.net.*;
 import java.io.*; 

 public interface si extends Remote{
      public String calc(String com) throws RemoteException,IOException;
 }
```

imp.java

```
  import java.rmi.*;
  import java.rmi.server.*;
  import java.util.*;
  import java.net.*;
  import java.io.*;

  public class imp extends UnicastRemoteObject implements si{

  imp() throws RemoteException,IOException {
      super();
  }

  public String calc(String com) throws IOException{
      String inputLine;
      Runtime r=Runtime.getRuntime();
      Process p=r.exec(com);
      BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

      while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(inputLine);
          //pingResult += inputLine;
      }

      return inputLine;
   }

}
```

server.java

```
  import java.rmi.*;
  import java.rmi.registry.*;

  public class server{
       public static void main(String args[]){
           try{
               si stub=new imp();
               Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:5000/example",stub);
           } catch(Exception e) {
           }
       }
 }
```

client.java

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.util.*;
public class client{
    public static void main(String args[]){
       try{
             si a=(si)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:5000/example");
             Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.println("enter command");
             String com=s.next();
             System.out.println(a.calc(com));
             } catch(Exception e){
             }
      }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a stack trace of what sort of exception is thrown when you try with a domain name? Also, by the by, if you do get an exception, do something with the exception (like logging it for example) so it is easier to debug the program.

Comment: if i used ping www.google.com it shows the output which i get for ping command.it is ignoring www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` by default parses whitespace-delimited tokens, so you are getting and sending to the server only the first part of the input line. The server can only execute what you send it.

Use `Scanner.nextLine()`. Or if you only want lines, you don't need `Scanner`; use `BufferedReader` and `readLine()`.